# How to find out the value of following functional?

Tags: functional-analysis

Consider the normed linear space $\mathbb{R}^2$ equipped with norm given by $\|(x,y)\|= |x|+|y|$ and the subspace $M = \{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 \  : \  x = y\}$. Let $f$ be the linear functional on $X$given by $f(x,y) = 3x$. If $g(x,y) = ax+by$, $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$, is a  Hahn Banach extension of $f$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$, then find $a-b$

Now is started with the condition that $f = g$ on $M$, so from there i get $a+b = 3$. But don't know how to go further. I also know that norm of both the functionals should be same but couldn't find the same.

Comment: I assume that $X$ in the question is a typo for $M$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** One way is to draw a picture of the unit ball of the space, plus the subspace. Notice that the subspace intersects the boundary of the ball at a flat side. Think about how the affine space given by $g(x,y)=\frac32$ must be situated in your picture.

**Edit:** Once the geometry is clear to you, it is easy to make a formal proof. The “flat side” I mentioned is spanned by two points $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$. Now write up the inequalities saying $g\le\frac32$ at these two points.

Comment: Any other way without geometry?

Comment: That's what the second paragraph is all about. Write $g(x,y)=ax+by$. You want $g(x,x)=f(x,x)=3x$, so $a+b=3$. And $g(1,0)\le\frac32$ gives you $a\le\frac32$, and you similarly get $b\le\frac32$. Now, combine these equalities and inequalities, and there is only one possibility.

Comment: ok great work, thanks'