# A doubt on applying Hahn-Banach to problems

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, hahn-banach-theorem

I had a doubt on Hahn-Banach continuous extension theorem.
Wikipedia says this:

> **Hahn–Banach continuous extension theorem —** Every continuous linear functional $f$ defined on a vector subspace $M$ of a (real or complex) locally convex topological vector space $X$ has a continuous linear extension $F$ to all of $X.$ If in addition  $X$ is a normed space, then this extension can be chosen so that its **dual norm** is equal to that of $f.$

Say I am working in $(\mathbb{R}^2,||\cdot ||_1).$ Here, for $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2,$ we have $||(x,y)||_1=|x|+|y|.$ So, any linear functional on the space $( \mathbb{R}^2,|| \cdot ||_1 )$ will reside in  $(\mathbb{R}^2,|| \cdot ||_{\infty}),$ as dual norm of $1-$ norm is $\infty-$ norm.

But, while reading [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2214132/how-to-find-out-the-value-of-following-functional) answer  in MSE, I am confused as to how the norm for the extension is taken.
First point to note is that $g$ lives in $\infty-$ norm.
As for the functional $g,$ we need $||g||=3= ||(a,b)||_{\infty}=\max \{|a|,|b| \}.$

So, either of $|a|$ or $|b|$ must be $3.$ Both can be $3$ also. But the answer in the linked part says that $a \leq \frac{3}{2}$ and $b \leq \frac{3}{2}$ making $||g|| \leq \frac{3}{2},$ a contradiction.

How is this achieved here ?
Whats happening here ??

Also, the solution given to the question involves simple geometry which I am not able to follow.
Is there any standard procedure/algorithm to find the Hahn-Banach extension given a space, its subspace and a functional on the subspace with all the necessary assumptions satisfied ?
please let me know of the simple references also.

**New edit:**
Using the notation in the linked question, I wrote (above in this question itself) that $||g||_\infty=3$ thinking that $||f||_{\infty}=3$ in $\mathcal{B}(M,\mathbb{R}).$

I have made a mistake there. $||f||_{\infty}=3$ is wrong.
In fact $||f||_{\infty}=\frac{3}{2}.$
Indeed,  $$||f||_{\infty} \text{ (in $M$ )}=\sup_{|(x,x)| \ne 0} \frac{|f(x,x)|}{||(x,x)||_1}= \sup_{|(x,x)| \ne 0} \frac{|3x|}{2|x|}=\frac{3}{2}.$$

So, we have that $||g||_\infty = \frac{3}{2}.$

And the rest of the work given in the linked answer is alright to me.
Can someone verify this for me, please ? Whether there is any gap in my understanding ?

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The proof of the Hahn Banach Theorem for extension by one dimension is constructive, and you can follow the procedure to construct the extension, one dimension at a time. It involves finding a sup and an inf, which is just a calculus exercise.

Comment: I find difficulty in reducing the functional analysis problem to calculus problem. That is where my understanding of this theorem is lacking behind. Please guide.

Comment: You can do it by brutal force. Refer to the proof of proposition 4.3 on page 18 of http://mtaylor.web.unc.edu/wp-content/uploads/sites/16915/2018/04/fctnl.pdf